# ruby on rails form not doing correct action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to edit a form, the route is controller/id/action for edit so for example

people/124321/edit

I'm trying to make this form submit to the update action using this code:

```
<% form_for :probe, @probe, :action => "update" do |f| %>
   ...
   ...
   ...
   <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

When I click submit, it gives me an error stating

Unknown Action. 
No action responded to (id).

**Edit**

The only thing in my routes specified for probes is map.resources :probes

RoR just did the people/124321/edit by itself when I generated the controller.

Rake routes shows this

```
probes       GET /probes(.:format) {:controller=>"probes", :action=>"index"}
             POST   /probes(.:format) {:controller=>"probes", :action=>"create"}
new_probe    GET    /probes/new(.:format) {:controller=>"probes", :action=>"new"}
edit_probe   GET    /probes/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"probes",action=>"edit"}
             GET    /probes/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"probes", :action=>"show"}
             PUT    /probes/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"probes", :action=>"update"}
             DELETE /probes/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"probes", :action=>"destroy"}
```

**Edit 2 Probe Controller**

```
    def edit
     @probe = Probe.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
    @probe = Probe.find(params[:id])
    debugger
    if @probe.update_attributes(params[:probe])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated probe."
      redirect_to probes_path
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post exactly what your route is?

Comment: That should be controller/action/id... right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sometimes looking at the generated HTML can help to see if the problem is with the controller or the view.  The HTML should explicitly have /people/<some id>/edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly since you have posted very little supporting details for your question, but my guess is that your routes file is set up such that the precedence of something matching `:controller/:action/:id` comes before the route you're aiming for, `:controller/:id/:action`.

Routes are evaluated top-down, first match wins.

I'll echo John's answer, too. You shouldn't need to specify `:action => 'update'`, and in fact these days I usually extract the form out of both `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` into a partial `_form.html.erb`. `form_for` will figure out if the object is a new record and POST to either the `create` or `update` action, as appropriate.

I have seen some situations in the past where route changes reloaded in development mode confuse the routing code, which is usually fixed by restarting the server.

`rake routes` is also a good debugging tool. Check the page source to see what Rails has used for the form's `action` attribute, then scan down the output of `rake routes` to see where the request will end up.

Comment: The only thing in my routes specified for probes is map.resources :probes

RoR just did the people/124321/edit by itself when I generated the controller (I'm assuming)

Comment: Is that the entire 'rake routes' output? Are there any routes that aren't using resources, but instead the older :controller/:action/:id form? Also, the ID for your Probe object looks different, from your comment in John's answer. There are embedded "+" characters there. Rails will probably interpret those as URL-encoded spaces, which may be confusing the router. Finally, what error do you get when you switch to the 'form_for' syntax John and I suggested?

Comment: I found the issue, forgot to update this. It had to actually do with a naming convention that was getting mixed up in rails. It was messing up more of what I thought (instead of just this issue) and after tracking it down for awhile, I was able to use the normal form for that John suggested. Both of you got me on the right track though, thank you. Appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using RESTful resources, then you should just be able to do this:

```
<% form_for(@probe) do |f| %>
  .
  .
  .
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Rails can work out whether you're creating a new record or updating an existing one. See [Binding a Form to an Object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) for further details.

Also, note the use of `f.submit` in my example. The `*_tag` helpers go together, so you wouldn't usually see a `form_for` helper with a `submit_tag`.

Comment: When I do this I get an error around the form_for line. The error occurred while evaluating nil.to_sym

Comment: That's probably because your @probe instance variable is nil in your controller's edit action (method). The edit action displays a form suitable for editing a model. The form then submits to the update action.

Comment: What is your value for @probe?

Comment: From ruby debugger in the edit action..........

irb(#<ProbesController:0x62d8f74>):001:0> @probe
=> #<Probe id: "PoXmvhvk+ORIH+p7", name: "gragrag", user_id: 1, online: nil, cre
ated_at: "2009-11-10 19:16:12", updated_at: "2009-11-10 19:16:12", status: 3, st
reet: "ragragra", city: "ragragra", country: nil, zip: "", state: "KS", contact_
name: "", contact_number: "", deleted: 0>

Answer (score 0):

"Unknown Action. No action responded to (id)." sounds like a routing problem.

Have you removed or commented out the default routes in your routes.rb file?

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

If the default routes are being run it could be swapping the id for the action?